# Scale down or drain node with running single replicas

Tags: kubernetes, microservices, google-kubernetes-engine

i am running single replicas of some applications with default **maxsurge** and **maxunavilable**  25%. using **kind: deployment** with **rollingupdate** replicas=1.

now if GKE scaling down the node it first deleting pod and after that creating a new pod on another node which creating some downtime for the application.

is there any solution? what is the best practices?

i can run multiple replicas of some services but not for all services.

what is the best way to handle this situation?

using node affinity? can anyone please share an example if possible?

thanks in advance.

Comment: A [pod disruption budget](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/) can temporarily keep the node from draining, but that won't help if your service can't run a second replica somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly on GKE, but probably there is the same as in AWS.

You can configure the service to prevent scale in actions on certain nodes, so, pair that with nodeAffinity, and you can have a deployment running always on a particular node which is configured to not be removed during scaling events.

UPDATE

well, in fact, reading the docs, you have everything you need documented https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#scheduling-and-disruption

Comment: i want to know how many minimum replicas you run and what type of affinity

Comment: @chagan we can't tell you this, this is up to you. You're the one who need to decide how many minimum replicas are needed to keep the service working with the expected performance. About the affinity, it's a simple label. You label those nodes you don't want to scale in with something (e.g do-not-scale), and then on the Pod definition you set the affinity to nodes matching that label.